# E/flutter ( 7193) al abrir el archivo json con Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

Estoy tratando de abrir este archivo json que está en activos en mi proyecto flutter pero no puedo.

Mi código es [este](https://pastebin.com/W4NPCAz5) en pastebin.

No entiendo por qué no está abriendo el archivo y enumerando los datos, está dando un error al abrir el archivo y enumerar los objetos en el principal. No entendí muy bien. ¿Alguien podría explicar o refactorizar el código?

En *pubspec.yaml* se ve así:

```yaml
assets:
    - assets/json/dados.json
```

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
 
void main() async{
 
  final String jsonData = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/dados.json');
 
  // Transforma o JSON numa lista de Maps que o Flutter entende.
  final listaRaw = jsonDecode(jsonData) as List;
  
  // Transforma a lista de Maps em uma lista do tipo da sua classe Usuario
  final List<Usuario> listaDeTodos = listaRaw.map((item) => Usuario.fromJson(item)).toList();
  
  // Para passar item a item
  for (final element in listaDeTodos) {
    print("Título: " + element.title);
  }
  
  // Para printar um item em específico
    print("\nTítulo do item 1: " + listaDeTodos[1].title);
  
}
 
class Usuario {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final bool completed;
 
  Usuario({required this.userId, required this.id, required this.title, required this.completed});
 
  factory Usuario.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){ 
    return  Usuario(
    userId: json['userId'],
    id: json['id'],
    title: json['title'],
    completed: json['completed']
    );
  }
}
```

```json
/////
arquivo dados.json
 
[{
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "delectus aut autem",
        "completed": false
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
        "completed": false
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 3,
        "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
        "completed": false
      }]
```

> /flutter ( 7193): #8 main package:mapeando_arquivo_json02/main.dart:6 E/flutter ( 7193): #9
> _runMain. (dart:ui/hooks.dart:134:23) E/flutter ( 7193): #10
> _delayEntrypointInvocation. (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19) E/flutter ( 7193): #11
> _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12) E/flutter ( 7193):

Comment: El código debe ir en la pregunta misma, no como enlace externo. Piénsalo: si más adelante alguien quiere ayudarte (ayudando así a otros con el mismo problema posteriormente), ¿cómo podrá hacerlo si el enlace llega a caer?

Comment: pero el código ya está en la pregunta, resulta que el código de lastebon y el publicado en la pregunta son los mismos, pero no puedo abrir el archivo y enumerar los objetos json

Comment: "E/flutter ( 7193)" es el error que te está mostrando, pero en alguna parte se debe mostrar la descripción del error como tal. Lo que estás mostrando son las ubicaciones 9, 10 y 11 del _trace_.

Comment: Estoy usando Visual Studio Code en Linux mint y en la consola de depuración solo muestra este resultado de error, no muestra nada más además de que investigué este número de error y no puedo encontrar ninguna solución.